# ¿Cómo hacer un contador con SharedPreferences que no se modifique cuando cambie un JSON? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

estoy desarrollando una aplicación y necesito evitar que se ingresen registros ya existentes provenientes de un JSON, la idea que estoy intentando hacer es: 
Tengo un JSON que posee 5 elementos dentro, los cuales necesito almacenar en la BD, para luego en un próximo inicio de la app poder reducir el trabajo realizado sólo ingresando los elementos nuevos desde la ultima vez que se inició la app.

Osea, que si la primera vez se ingresaron 5 y abro por segunda vez la app y ahora hay 7 elementos, entonces espero sólo poder trabajar los 2 elementos que han cambiado.

Mi idea es usar SharedPreferences para almacenar un contador que mide la longitud del JSON y así poder comparar la longitud anterior con la longitud actual del JSON. Pero mi problema es que el SharedPreferences con permanece con el mismo valor de la ultima vez que inició la app, si no que se sobrescribe con la nueva longitud del JSON.

Aquí el código donde recorro y guardo la longitud en un SharedPreferences.

```
private void handleActionRun() {

    String url2 = "http://10.0.2.2/xampp/BdApp/twitter/mentions_timeline.php?username=" + twitter_user + "&accesstoken=" + twitter_token + "&accesstokensecret=" + twitter_secret;
    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url2);
    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {

            JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            int cantidad = jsonObj.length();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString(getString(R.string.cantidad_key), String.valueOf(cantidad));
            editor.commit();
            Log.e(TAG, "Cantidad " + cantidad);
            String cantidad_twitter = sharedPref.getString((getString(R.string.cantidad_key)), "");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cantidad_twitter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Esta habiendo problemas para cargar el JSON");
    }
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Primero puedes mostrar la cantidad actual y mostrar la anterior que fue guardada previamente, posteriormente puedes guardar la cantidad actual que sería la siguiente ocasión la cantidad anterior:

```
  try {
         JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
         int cantidadActual = jsonObj.length();
         Log.e(TAG, "Cantidad Actual " + cantidadActual);
         String cantidad_twitter = sharedPref.getString((getString(R.string.cantidad_key)), "");
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cantidad actual: " + cantidadActual + " ,Cantidad anterior: " + cantidad_twitter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         //Despues de mostrar los valores ahora puedes guardar la cantidad actual para que la siguiente ocasión sea la anterior.

         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
         editor.putString(getString(R.string.cantidad_key), String.valueOf(cantidadActual));
         editor.commit();

     } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
     }
```